# Vertex correction cut-off

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, correlation-functions, regularization

I'm trying to retrieve the Vertex cut-off solved by Bjorken and Drell in their book (J.D.Bjorken S.D.Drell-Relativistic Quantum Mechanics Bjorken Drell (1964)-McGraw-Hill (1964).
The main issue is that I'm not able to do it. More specifically I start studying the divergent part

$$\int_0^{\infty}{dz_1 dz_2 dz_3 \delta(1-z_1-z_2-z_3)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^4k \dfrac{\not{k}\gamma_\mu \not{k}}{(k^2-c-i\epsilon)^3}   ,$$
where $c = c(\lambda) = m^2(1-z_1)-q^2z_2z_3+\lambda^2z_1$, and $\lambda$ a small photon mass that protect us from infrared divergence. Subsequently I use this approximation, recommended by the book, to rewrite the numerator: 
$$k_{\mu}k_{\nu} = \dfrac{1}{4}k^2 g^{\mu \nu}$$ 
Performing a Wick Rotation, in order to integrate in spherical coordinates, I obtain (dropping out prefactors, and performing the trivial angular integration):
$$\gamma_{\mu} \int_0^\infty dz_1 dz_2 dz_3 \delta(1-z_1-z_2-z_3) \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{|k|^5}{(|k|^2+c(\lambda)+i\epsilon)^3}. $$
Where now $|k|$ is the Euclidean module of the 4-vector $k$. 
And here we come to the problem. The advice is to perform the cut-off, i.e. replace the last integrand with $$\dfrac{|k|^5}{(|k|^2+c(\lambda)+i\epsilon)^3} - \dfrac{|k|^5}{(|k|^2+c(\Lambda)+i\epsilon)^3}.$$ But doing this I can't obtain the analytic function like the one written in the book. Someone can help me? The precise reference is the book mentioned at the beginning and the page is 170.

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what you tried after making this substitution? That is you should already be able to perform the momentum integral, unless that is the issue.